# Multiple Forms in a single JSP having fields with the same name/id attribute

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have two forms in a JSP page.

```
<form id="myForm1">
<input type="text" name="formText" id="formText"></input>
.
.
.


</form>

<form id="myForm2">
<input type="text" name="formText" id="formText"></input>
.
.
.


</form>
```

In my JavaScript I'm able to make a distinction between the two text boxes despite both of them having the same name/ID using the form ID like this

```
document.forms["myForm1"]["formText"].value and 
document.forms["myForm2"]["formText"].value return different values.
```

How can I make this distinction in Java code? For example, what will request.getParameter("formText") return? I want to be able to make this distinction in my business end. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Element IDs should be unique within the entire document and that's a rule you should follow. Btw, you could use 2 input hidden fields with same name but different values, then on server side you should be able to reach your goal.

```
<form id="myForm1">
 <input type="text" name="formText" id="formText"></input>
 <input type="hidden" name="whichform" value="myForm1"></input>
 .
 .


</form>

<form id="myForm2">
 <input type="text" name="formText" id="formText"></input>
 <input type="hidden" name="whichform" value="myForm2"></input>
 .
 .


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your business logic for the two forms differs, you could consider targeting the form's actions to different handlers - one for each form.

```
<form id="myForm1" action="form1action.jsp">
```

In that case form1action.jsp will receive all values if form1 is submitted, form2action.jsp all values for form2.jsp

This allows a cleaner design as you wouldn't need to touch the form1 stuff if you add a field to form2.

Of cause Servlets might be better suited as handlers...